# Unable to perform onClick action on a ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, onclick

This is my code .  I am getting force Close error when press on item . Stuck in this program . Didn't find a right solution

```
myList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myList);
Adapter = new MobileArrayAdapter(FileShare.this, MOBILE_OS);
myList.setAdapter(Adapter);
myList.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{        
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
    {           
        // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your message here", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();             
        Intent i = new Intent(FileShare.this, sharedView.class);
        Intent pickFileIntent = new Intent();
        pickFileIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        pickFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        pickFileIntent.setType("*/*");
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(pickFileIntent, getText(R.string.choosefile_title));
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
        startActivity(i);       
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat so that your problem can be understandable

Comment: well it might b while calling your new activity,,,,use log to check if its listview creating a prob or your next activity

Comment: This is my logcat           10-25 16:25:27.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 16:25:27.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1084): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.pcloud.fileshare/com.pcloud.fileshare.mainPages.sharedView}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-25 16:25:27.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
10-25 16:25:27.242: E/AndroidRuntime(1084):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)

Comment: share full logcat info.
Also share your layout.

Comment: Wait what are you doing??? You are trying to launch two activities at a time? What dis lines means? `startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, PICK_FILE_REQUEST);
        startActivity(i);     `

Answer (score 0):

Add `ComponentInfo` in your manifest file like this

```
<activity android:name="ComponentInfo" android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                    android:configChanges="orientation"></activity>
```

I guess this will help you...

Comment: any changes in logcat after doing this?post your logcat in your question it self so that it will be readable

Comment: If your problem solved then Please accept the answer otherwise give the update about the problem

Comment: That same logcat is appearing and problem is still there .

Comment: Its giving null pointer on ActivityThread.java:2663 this class can you share this class code with highliting the line where null pointer is occuring??